# Algorithm for testing for equivalence of two algebraic expressions

Tags: algorithm, math, linear-algebra, algebra

I have to write a program that tests whether two algebraic expressions are equivalent. It should follow MDAS precedence and parenthesis grouping. To solve the problem about precedence, I'm thinking I should implement a Infix to Postfix Notation converter for these expressions. But by doing this, I could not conclude their equivalence.

The program should look like this:
User Input: a*(a+b) = a*a + a*b
Output : Equivalent

For this problem I'm not allowed to use Computer Algebraic Systems or any external libraries. Please don't post the actual code if you have one, I just need an idea to work this problem out.

Comment: Could you describe what your approach was that didn't work? I would think that if you put both expressions into the same standard form, you should be able to compare them by traversing and comparing two tree structures.

Comment: What result your program must display for these two algebraic expressions: `1/(a-a)` and `2/(a-a)`?

Comment: also `x + y` and `a + b` are equal?

Comment: ^ x+y and a+b shouldn't be equal

Comment: mbratch At first I actually wanted to simplify the expressions first to its standard form but realized it would be tedious (I guess), and also there is a problem on identifying whether the expressions are simplified or not. Can you elaborate on how I can make an expression be in its standard form inside a program?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff the program should say that it's nonequivalent. I'm not that concerned on checking whether the expression is valid. But I think 1/0 (constants involved) is an exception

Comment: @RomelioTavasJr. - IMHO, the two expressions are corresponding to the only function `f(a)` with empty domain, so they should be considered equivalent.  And what about `(x*x-1)/(x-1)` and `x+1`?

Comment: @RomelioTavasJr. - Why you consider `(a-a)/1` and `(a-a)/2` as equivalent, but their reciprocals - not equivalent? :-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff (x*x-1)/(x-1) and x+1 should be equivalent, since when simplified x+1 = x+1. And in the case of (a-a)/1 and (a-a)/2 should be equivalent, since 0 = 0 when simplified, and the reciprocal of 0 should be 0 right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function that check if two algebraic expressions are equal in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60876231/function-that-check-if-two-algebraic-expressions-are-equal-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

That's an idea:
You need to implement building [expression tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree) first because it's a very natural representation of expression.
Then maybe you'll need to simplify it by open brackets and etc. using associative or distributive algebraic properties.
Then you'll have to compare trees. It's not obvious because you need to take care of all branch permutations in commutative operations and etc. E.g. you can sort them (I mean branches) and then compare for equality. Also you need to keep in mind possible renaming of parameters, i.e. a + b need to be equal x + y.

Comment: In building the expression tree, do I have to use the postfix notation so arithmetic precedence won't be compromised?

Comment: @RomelioTavasJr. yes it's a good idea to translate to prefix or postfix notation first or you can build tree on the fly using these methods

Answer (score 1):

If you are not allowed to evaluate the expressions, you will have to parse them out into expression trees.

After that, I would get rid of all parenthesis by multiplying/dividing all members so a(b - c) becomes a*b - a*c.

Then convert all expressions back to strings, making sure you have all members alphabetically sorted (a*b, not b*a) ,remove all spaces and compare strings.