# Function that check if two algebraic expressions are equal in javascript

Tags: javascript, algebra

```
var Answer = '2a + 5b' // downloaded from database
var input = '5*b+ 2*a' // user input after calculating some algebraic expression. 

if (Answer == input){
    // tell student he solved the math problem correctly. 
}
```

I want a function so that the above if-statement return true. My problem is that my answer and user input is a string, and when compared they are not equal. The user however have solved the initial problem correct.

Comment: you'll need some complicated code to *evaluate* the mathematical expressions - good luck

Comment: Check out reverse polish notation and the shunting-yard algorithm. You'll have to actually parse both the answer and the input, and then collapse them. It's not trivial.

Comment: Could you tell us more about the types of problems you're dealing with? If they all fit this format, then you could get away with cheating (e.g not actually parsing, just using a RegEx or something similar to check that they both contain the same functional parts). But that would be pattern matching, and would break if you have any harder problems. **I don't know if we can answer this unless you edit your question and give us a few more answer / input combos.** Also, what are the edge cases? Should `a*a` and `a^2` both be valid answers? How about `(5*b) + 2*a`? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Even though certain forms of algebraic expressions -such as low-degree polynomials-- are evidently easy to test for equality or equivalence, a general and complete method (and hence an algorithm) cannot exist, because there exist forms of algebraic expressions for which the problem (of deciding their equality) is undecidable, as it was proved by the [Richardson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem):

> Richardson's theorem establishes a limit on the extent to which an
> algorithm can decide whether certain mathematical expressions are
> equal. It states that for a certain fairly natural class of
> expressions, it is undecidable whether a particular expression E
> satisfies the equation E = 0, and similarly undecidable whether the
> functions defined by expressions E and F are everywhere equal (in
> fact, E = F if and only if E − F = 0). It was proved in 1968 by
> computer scientist Daniel Richardson of the University of Bath.